# Wind patterns on a tidally locked planets contradict my logic (looking for correction)

Tags: science-based, weather, tidally-locked, wind

My take on the wind patterns on a tidally locked planet (TDL) does not lead to the information given in papers and videos. Please tell me where I went wrong.

**My take:**

On a TLP, the sub-solar point is a region of low air pressure (due to its high temperature), while the night side has relative higher air pressure. Wind flows from high to low air pressure, resulting in a wind pattern as depicted below (ground level).

[image]

Additionally, the coriolis effect leads to (ground level) winds to the west, similar to earth (earth has three cells per hemisphere, but since this planet rotates slower and for simplicity, it has only one cell per hemisphere - also, I'm assuming the same direction of rotation as earth); see below.

[image]

That would result in an overall pattern like this:

[image]

**H O W E V E R,**
this is not consistent with information I found online.

Most prominent, there is [this paper](https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.1315215111) which looks into ocean currents, but since they are influenced by wind, they seem contrary to the logic above.

[image]

Furthermore, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LifRswfCxFU) explains that the situation is as depicted below and thus coherent with what the research paper suggests.

[image]

**Please help me figure out why my understanding of wind patterns does not match the results of the research paper and the information in the video. Thanks!**

Comment: Unless the planet is very very close to its primary, on a tidally locked planet the Coriolis force is *tiny*, because it scales with the square of the angular velocity of the rotating frame of reference. For example, if Earth would be tidally locked to the sun, the magnitude of the Coriolis effect would be 130,000 times smaller and completely negligible.

Comment: This seems like it might be better asked on the physics stackexchange.

Comment: @AlexP I agree, however, even if you don't consider the Coriolis force, the paper and the video don't make sense to me.

Comment: The planet considered in the paper is *extremely close* to its star. It has an orbital period of about 36 days, which means that the magnitude of the Coriolis effect is about 100 times smaller than here on Earth. The is small, but not negligible. P.S. Air must *circulate*. You cannot have strong winds coming from three directions and only a weak wind going off in the remaining fourth direction -- where does the air go? Overall, the paper describes the results of actual computer simulations. I would say that the results are to be accepted as good in the specific given conditions.

Comment: That's why I wrote "ground level" - the winds at the solar pole meet, rise (due to being heated) and circle back to the night side while cooling off. 

Hadley Cell is the term for this type of loop, I think.